# Chern-Simons for 2n-dimensional manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

In the literature I can only find Chern-Simons terms  for odd-dimensional manifolds. For example, for a $G$-bundle over a 3-dimensional manifold we have $A \wedge dA + 2/3 * A \wedge A \wedge A$ with $A$ being a $\mathfrak{g}$-valued 1-form. Why can't I write such forms for even-dimensional manifolds?

Comment: Cross-listed: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/51603/chern-simons-term

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It has to do with the fact that the characteristic classes (over the reals) of a principal  $G$-bundle have *even* degree. We can associate  Chern-Simons-like theory  to each characteristic class of  degree $2k$ together with a $G$-bundle  $P$   over  a manifold of dimension  $2k-1$.

To be a bit more technical a Chern-Simons-like form is asssociated to the following data

**1.** A homogeneous polynomial $\Phi$ of degree $k$ on the Lie algebra  of $G$ invariant  under the action of $G$ by conjugation.

**2.** A  principal $G$-bundle  $P\to M$ over $M$.

**3.** A pair of connections $\nabla^0, \nabla^1$ on $P\to M$.

The Chern-Weil theory  produces two **closed** forms

$$ \Phi(\nabla^0),\Phi(\nabla^1)\in \Omega^{2k}(M) $$

and  a form

$$ T\Phi(\nabla^1,\nabla^0)\in \Omega^{2k-1}(M), $$

such that

$$ d T\Phi(\nabla^1,\nabla^0)=  \Phi(\nabla^1)-\Phi(\nabla^0). $$

(For details see Chapter 8 of [these  notes](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf).)

The  *transgression* form $T\Phi(\nabla^1,\nabla^0)$ is the one used in Chern-Simons  theories. It depends on two connections, but usually $\nabla^0$ is some fixed  connection.

Comment: Of course you can consider Chern-Simons forms on any manifold. But integrating them over the manifold - to get a numerical invariant - only works if the dimension of the manifold equals the degree of the form.